# Trouble with adding/removing a class in Jquery

Tags: jquery, class, addition

I am trying to make a navigation menu that when a link is clicked, loads content into a hidden div, then shows the hidden div, then changed the class of the list item. If the same link is clicked again the class reverts back to what it was before and then the content div becomes hidden.

Here is a url
view-source:http://www.scottjraney.com/javatest/

Here is the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("a.1").click(function(){
        $("div#hidden").load("/javatest/content1.html");
        $("div#hidden").slideDown();
        $("a").removeClass("1").addClass("1-change");
    });
    $("a.1-change").click(function(){
        $("div#hidden").slideUp();
        $("a").removeClass("1-change").addClass("1");
    }); 
});
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using the .click() function instead of [.live('click')](http://api.jquery.com/live/). the live() method allows any element (even something created in the future) to have that listener attached to it.

when the page loads, there are no '1-change' elements, so it has nothing to attach the listener to.

Comment: I appreciate the help, I am new to jquery (and I'm sure it is obvious). I went ahead and added the .live('click') function and applied it to the other links and it seems to be getting close to working. But after a few clicks on links it starts to get strange. Here is a url http://www.scottjraney.com/javatest/

Comment: also because you're using $("a"), instead use $(this)

Answer (score -1):

Try not starting your class names with numeric values. FF and IE used to fail at this. It isn't strictly invalid - but can cause problems.